# How to remove the extra space on the left and the right of the default BarChart?

Tags: charts

[image]

```
pbdomains = <|
       "Overall " -> Around[2.6, 0.04], 
       "PB" -> Around[4.25, 0.06]
|>;

BarChart[pbdomains, ChartStyle -> "BrightBands", 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 28, Bold, 
   GrayLevel[0]}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"", " Count"}, 
 BarSpacing -> Tiny, 
 ChartLabels -> Callout[Automatic, Above, Appearance -> "Balloon"]]
```

Comment: @Carl Lange . Many thanks!

Comment: Add `PlotRange -> {{0.5, 2.5}, All}`.

Comment: @Rohit Namjoshi. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PlotRangePadding`.

```
pbdomains = <|
       "Overall " -> Around[2.6, 0.04], 
       "PB" -> Around[4.25, 0.06]
|>;

BarChart[pbdomains, ChartStyle -> "BrightBands", 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 28, Bold, 
   GrayLevel[0]}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"", " Count"}, 
 BarSpacing -> Tiny, 
 ChartLabels -> Callout[Automatic, Above, Appearance -> "Balloon"],
 PlotRangePadding -> {{-1.4, -1.37}, {None, Scaled[0.2]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

[image]Based on Rohit Namjoshi solution:

```
pbdomains = <|"Overall " -> Around[2.6, 0.04], 
   "PB" -> Around[4.25, 0.06]|>;

BarChart[pbdomains, ChartStyle -> "BrightBands", 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 28, Bold, 
   GrayLevel[0]}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"", " Count"}, 
 BarSpacing -> Tiny, 
 ChartLabels -> Callout[Automatic, Above, Appearance -> "Balloon"], 
 PlotRange -> {{0.5, 2.5}, All}]
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Use the (undocumented) option `"FixedBarSpacing"` as  `"FixedBarSpacing" -> True` or as  `Method -> {"FixedBarSpacing" -> True}`

```
BarChart[pbdomains, ChartStyle -> "BrightBands", 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 28, Bold, 
      GrayLevel[0]}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"", " Count"}, 
  ChartLabels -> Callout[Automatic, Above, Appearance -> "Balloon"],
  "FixedBarSpacing" -> True]
```

[image: `[![enter image description here][1]][1]]

**2.** Use `{pbdomains}` as the first argument and use the option `BarSpacing -> {Tiny, 1}`:

```
BarChart[{pbdomains},
  BarSpacing -> { Tiny, 1},
  ChartStyle -> "BrightBands", 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 28, Bold, GrayLevel[0]}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"", " Count"}, 
  ChartLabels -> Callout[Automatic, Above, Appearance -> "Balloon"]]
```

[image]