# Decrease padding around Bar Chart

Tags: charts

I don't like the default amount of padding / white space around BarChart. How can I specify it?

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: `PlotRangePadding->None` does't work

Comment: You can use `AxesOrigin` but it seems a little un-intuitive how to specify and I'm not sure how it scales.

Comment: possible duplicate: [How to remove the extra space on the left and the right of the default BarChart?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/199148/125)

Comment: I think you're right. But there have been some neater solutions posted this time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definitely an example of how vexing it often can be to get flexible graphical output from some built ins in Mathematica, where one is left struggling against the defaults.

A way out may be to force `RectangleChart` into use, since that function apparently makes much more reasonable choices on plot ranges. `RectangleChart` needs explicit bar widths, though, so here is a quick hack to add those to a simple dataset:

```
fakeBarChart = RectangleChart[Transpose@{ConstantArray[1, Length[#]], #}] &;

fakeBarChart[{1, 2, 3}]
```

[image: rectangle plots]

No doubt this will fail messily for more complex datasets, but it may still be easier to fix *that* than to fight with the silly choices that `BarChart` makes.

Comment: This seems like the neatest solution so far.

Answer (score 4):

**1.** Use the (undocumented) option `"FixedBarSpacing"` as `"FixedBarSpacing" -> True` or as `Method -> {"FixedBarSpacing" -> True}`:

```
d = Range[3]; 

Row[{BarChart[d, ImageSize -> 300], 
     BarChart[d,  ImageSize -> 300, "FixedBarSpacing" -> True]}, 
  Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

**2.** Using `{d}` as the first argument and using the option `BarSpacing -> {Automatic, 1}` removes the unwanted spaces on the left and right:

```
BarChart[{d}, BarSpacing -> {Automatic, 1}]
```

[image]

**3.** Alternatively, a combination of `PlotRange` + `AxesOrigin` + `DisplayFunction`:

```
BarChart[d, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.4, Length[d] + .5}, All}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
 DisplayFunction -> (Show[#, AxesOrigin -> {0.4, 0}] &)]
```

[image]

**Note:** One would expect using `AxesOrigin -> {0.4, 0}` directly would have worked. But, somehow, user-specified `AxesOrigin` option values are overridden.

Answer (score 2):

It's annoying I couldn't find an easy way to do this. You can remove some of the white space if you pad with extra zeros on the right (you can also use `PadRight[{1, 2, 3}, 6]`) and limit the x-axis `PlotRange`:

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0}, BarSpacing -> 0.1, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 3.5}, Automatic}]
```

[image: bar chart padding removed]