# How can I add a horizontal line to my BarChart?

Tags: plotting, charts

This is my first time asking a question on the Mathematica StackExchange. As the title says I'm looking for a way to add a horizontal line across my bar graph. The code I currently have is as follows:

```
BarPi = BarChart[dataExperimentalPi, 
  ChartLabels -> {A, B, C, D, E, F}, PlotRange -> {3, 3.25}]
```

I have a screenshot of the desired output below (along with my code at present).

[image: Example of what I would like it to look like]

Thank you so much for the help in advance.

Answer (score 5):

There might be better ways, but you can try `Epilog`

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, ChartLabels -> {"A", "B", "C"}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Thick, Line[{{-0.4, 0.5}, {3.45, 0.5}}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The problem is that I had to try different starting/ending values for the `x coordinate` to get the red line to match as needed, this is because the scales are different.   For your case, you'd have to do the same. Try few values to make the red line starts and ends exactly where you want it.

Another option is to use `Show`

```
p1 = BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, ChartLabels -> {"A", "B", "C"}];
p2 = Graphics[{Red, Thick, Line[{{-0.4, 0.5}, {3.45, 0.5}}]}];
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

You could use grid lines:

```
BarChart[
  {1, 2, 3}, ChartLabels -> {"A", "B", "C"},
  GridLines -> {None, {0.5}},
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick],
  Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}
]
```

[image: result with gridlines]

Answer (score 2):

1. `nItems` can be used to change the number of data items.
2. A `Red` line is drawn at the `Mean` value of the data items.
3. I have used [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224075/decrease-padding-around-bar-chart/224121#224121) answer by @kglr for the `FixedBarSpacing` option that appears in Red.
4. My setup: v12.2.0 Win7-x64.
5. I hope this gives you the necessary pointers.

---

```
nItems = 13;
data = 3 + RandomReal[{-0.7, 0.7}, nItems];
m = Mean@data;
BarChart[data
 , ChartLabels -> CharacterRange[
    "A", "Z"][[1 ;; Length@data]
   ]
 , "FixedBarSpacing" -> True
 , PlotRange -> {
   {0.4, Length[data] + 0.4 + 0.1}
   , {0, Ceiling[Max@data, 0.5]}
   }
 , AxesOrigin -> {0.4, 0}
 , AspectRatio -> 1/3
 , ImageSize -> Large
 , ImagePadding -> {{Scaled[0.04], Scaled[0.01]}
   , {Scaled[0.04], Scaled[0.01]}}
 , Epilog -> {
   Red, Thick
   , Line[{
     Scaled[{0, 0}, {0.4, m}]
     , Scaled[{1, 0}, {0.4, m}]
     }]
   }
 ]
```

[image]